# Magento 2.3.1 | Continuously Redirecting To Homepage & Getting "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page" Error

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, magento2.3, magento2.3.1, form-key

I am working on a payment module using Magento 2.3.1. I have already implemented `CsrfAwareActionInterface` and 2 of its methods (`createCsrfValidationException()` & `validateForCsrf()`) in my controller just before `execute()` function. It redirects me to the payment gateway website successfully and makes the purchase.

However, I have set this below URL as my Return URL:

> https://website.com/checkout/onepage/success/

But Magento 2.3.1 redirects to the homepage and throws **Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page** error. I have tried to search for all possible solutions but to no avail.

I have already confirmed it from the payment gateway side, and it is perfectly returning to my mentioned above URL. I am not sure that if there's something wrong with Magento 2.3 because before implementing `CsrfAwareActionInterface`, the code was working correctly on previous Magento 2 versions.

Here is the controller's code:

```
<?php
namespace PayAxis\PayAxisPaymentModule\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Index extends Action implements CsrfAwareActionInterface
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory  */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    private $orderFactory;
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public $currency;
    public $Amount;
    public $ExpiryTime;
    public $_TxnRefNumber;
    public $_TxnDateTime;
    public $_Description;

    const XML_PATH_ACTIONURL = 'payment/payaxispaymentmethod/actionurl';
    const XML_PATH_MERCHANTID = 'payment/payaxispaymentmethod/merchantid';
    const XML_PATH_PASSWORD = 'payment/payaxispaymentmethod/password';
    const XML_PATH_RETURNURL = 'payment/payaxispaymentmethod/returnurl';
     const XML_PATH_IntegritySalt = 'payment/payaxispaymentmethod/IntegritySalt';
      const XML_PATH_ExpiryHours = 'payment/payaxispaymentmethod/ExpiryHours';

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $salesOrderFactory,
       \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,        
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
        /* array $data = [] */
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_orderFactory = $salesOrderFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        //$data = [];
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function createCsrfValidationException(RequestInterface $request): ?InvalidRequestException
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $orderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
        $order =  $this->_orderFactory->load($orderId);
         $orderItems = $order->getdata();  
         $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

        $ActionURL = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_ACTIONURL, $storeScope);
               $MerchantID = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_MERCHANTID, $storeScope);
                      $Password = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_PASSWORD, $storeScope);
                             $ReturnURL = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_RETURNURL, $storeScope);
                              $IntegritySalt = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_IntegritySalt, $storeScope);
                               $ExpiryHours = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_ExpiryHours, $storeScope);

      foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item)
      {
         $ProdustIds[]= $item->getProductId(); 
         $proName[] = $item->getName(); // product name
      }



        $_Description = implode(",", $proName);
        $currency = $orderItems['base_currency_code'];
        $Amount= $orderItems['grand_total'];
        $final_orderid = $orderItems['increment_id'];
        $_AmountTmp = $Amount*100;
        $_AmtSplitArray = explode('.', $_AmountTmp);
        $_FormattedAmount = $_AmtSplitArray[0];
        $ExpiryTime = date('YmdHis', strtotime("+".$ExpiryHours." hours"));
     //   $ExpiryTime = date('YmdHis', strtotime("+5 days"));
        $_TxnRefNumber = "TXN1". date('YmdHis');
        $_TxnDateTime =   date('YmdHis');
        $pp_language = 'EN';
        $pp_version = '1.1';

        //Calculating Hash
        $SortedArrayOld =$IntegritySalt.'&'.$_FormattedAmount.'&'.$final_orderid.'&'.$_Description.'&'.$pp_language.'&'.$MerchantID.'&'.$Password.'&'.$ReturnURL.'&'.$currency.'&'.$_TxnDateTime.'&'.$ExpiryTime.'&'.$_TxnRefNumber.'&'.$pp_version.'&'.'1'.'&'.'2'.'&'.'3'.'&'.'4'.'&'.'5';
        $pp_securehash = hash_hmac('sha256', $SortedArrayOld, $IntegritySalt);


        $RequestLog ="Request sent to Payment Gateway : Start \n" ;
        $RequestLog .="pp_Version :".$pp_version."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_TxnType  : \n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_Language  :".$pp_language."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_MerchantID  :".$MerchantID."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_SubMerchantID  : \n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_Password  :".$Password."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_BankID  : \n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_ProductID  : \n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_TxnRefNo  :".$_TxnRefNumber."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_Amount  :".$_FormattedAmount."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_TxnCurrency  :".$currency."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_TxnDateTime  :".$_TxnDateTime."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_BillReference  :".$final_orderid."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_Description  :".$_Description."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_TxnExpiryDateTime  :".$ExpiryTime."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_ReturnURL  :".$ReturnURL."\n";
        $RequestLog .= "pp_SecureHash :".$pp_securehash."\n";

        $RequestLog .= "ppmpf_1  : 1\n";
        $RequestLog .= "ppmpf_2  : 2\n";
        $RequestLog .= "ppmpf_3  : 3\n";
        $RequestLog .= "ppmpf_4  : 4\n";
        $RequestLog .= "ppmpf_5  : 5\n";
        $RequestLog .="Request sent to Payment Gateway : End \n";

        $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->addDebug($RequestLog);

        echo "<body onload=\"submitForm()\"></body>";
          echo "<script>function submitForm() { document.jsform.submit(); }</script>";
            echo "<form name=\"jsform\" method=\"post\" action=\"$ActionURL\">";
              //echo "<input type='hidden' name='".htmlentities($a)."' value='".htmlentities($b)."'>";
               echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_Version' value='1.1' >";
                 echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_TxnType' value=''>";
                   echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_Language' value='EN'>";
                     echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_MerchantID' value='".$MerchantID."' >";
                       echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_SubMerchantID' value='' >";
                         echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_Password' value='".$Password."' >";
                           echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_BankID' value=''>";
                             echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_ProductID' value=''>";
                               echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_TxnRefNo' value='".$_TxnRefNumber."'>";
                                 echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_Amount' value='".$_FormattedAmount."'>";
                                  echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_TxnCurrency' value='".$currency."'>";
                                     echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_TxnDateTime' value='".$_TxnDateTime."'>";
                                       echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_BillReference' value='".$final_orderid."'>";
                                         echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_Description' value='".$_Description."'>";
                                           echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_TxnExpiryDateTime' value='".$ExpiryTime."'>";

                                               echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_ReturnURL' value='".$ReturnURL."' >";
                                               echo "<input type='hidden' name='pp_SecureHash' value='".$pp_securehash."' >";

                                                echo "<input type='hidden' name='ppmpf_1' value='1'>";
                                                echo "<input type='hidden' name='ppmpf_2' value='2'>";
                                                 echo "<input type='hidden' name='ppmpf_3' value='3'>";
                                                 echo "<input type='hidden' name='ppmpf_4' value='4'>";
                                                  echo "<input type='hidden' name='ppmpf_5' value='5'>";
                                                  echo "</form>";
                                                  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.jsform.submit();</script>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Sir I'm facing exactly the same issue even we both have the same class I'm using it for **JazzCash** Sir did you get the solution??? if *Yes* then Please Share with me I'm almost working on this error around two days

Comment: n for me it was working perfectly on M 2.2.10 but on M 2.3.2 it sending me to homepage with the same error

Comment: Sir I need a bit of help in the above scenario... can you please help me a bit?

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2.3.0: Implement below code to skip the CSRF check on your custom route called outside Magento environment. This implementation does not break core frontend/adminhtml routes

> Vender/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator">
        <plugin name="csrf_validator_skip" type="Module\Vendor\Plugin\CsrfValidatorSkip" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vender/Module/Plugin/CsrfValidatorSkip.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CsrfValidatorSkip
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $action
     */
    public function aroundValidate(
        $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $request,
        $action
    ) {
        /* Magento 2.1.x, 2.2.x */
        if ($request->getModuleName() == 'Your_Module_frontName_Here') {
            return; // Skip CSRF check
        }
        /* Magento 2.3.x */
        if (strpos($request->getOriginalPathInfo(), 'Add_Controller_frontName') !== false) {
            return; // Skip CSRF check
        }
        $proceed($request, $action); // Proceed Magento 2 core functionalities
    }
}
```

copied from [This](https://gist.github.com/ananth-iyer/59ecfabcbca73d6c2e3eeb986ed2f3c4) I hope it will also work for you as well